# clear:both not affecting columns correctly

Tags: html, css

## Issue

I have four columns in my footer at 25% width each.

For tablets, the width becomes 50% - two per line.

However, I cannot align the first two and second two columns.

Here is an image to show how they look currently:

[image]

I'm trying to get them to look like:

```
|-------------------|
|         |         |
|    1    |    2    |
|         |         |
|-------------------|
|         |         |
|    3    |    4    |
|         |         |
|-------------------|
```

I'm trying to achieve this by appending `clear:both;` after the second element in the CSS file for smaller devices.

However, this is not working:

```
div#footer div.wrapper div.column:nth-child(2):after {
  content:'';
  display:block;
  clear:both;
}
```

## Code

```css
div.column { float: left; }

div#footer div.wrapper div.column { width:50%; }

div#footer div.wrapper div.column:nth-child(2):after {
  content:'';
  display:block;
  clear:both;
}

/*For testing purposes... */

div.column {
  background: black;
  color:white;
  border: 1px solid red;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

```html
<footer><div id="footer">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="column">
      <h4>Important Links</h4>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="index.php">Homepage</a></li>
        <li><a href="./privacy.php">Privacy Policy</a></li>
        <li><a href="./terms.php">Terms of Use</a></li>
      </ul>

      <h4>Social</h4>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-fw"></i>Twitter</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-linkedin fa-fw"></i>LinkedIn</a></li>
      </ul>   
    </div>

    <div class="column">
      <p>Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet</p>    
    </div>

    <div class="column">
      <p>Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet</p>
    </div>

    <div class="column" style="text-align:right;">
      <p>Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet</p>
    </div>

    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
  </div>
</div></footer>
```

Comment: How about giving the blocks a fixed height?

Comment: The content has variable height in each column

Comment: OK. Do you really need the borders and/or do the blocks have a background color (or is transparent fine)?

Comment: The borders and background are only there to illustrate the boundaries of each section - they have a transparent background and border

Comment: Pretty sure that floating isn't going to be an option here...this feels like a masonry type question...or perhaps `flexbox`

Comment: May `display: table-cell` and `display: table-row` help? http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```css
div.column { float: left; }

div#footer div.wrapper div.column { width:50%; }

div#footer div.wrapper div.columnthree {
  clear:both;
}

/*For testing purposes... */

div.column {
  background: black;
  color:white;
  border: 1px solid red;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

```html
<footer><div id="footer">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="column">
      <h4>Important Links</h4>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="index.php">Homepage</a></li>
        <li><a href="./privacy.php">Privacy Policy</a></li>
        <li><a href="./terms.php">Terms of Use</a></li>
      </ul>

      <h4>Social</h4>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-fw"></i>Twitter</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-linkedin fa-fw"></i>LinkedIn</a></li>
      </ul>   
    </div>

    <div class="column">
      <p>Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet</p>    
    </div>

    <div class="column columnthree">
      <p>Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet</p>
    </div>

    <div class="column" style="text-align:right;">
      <p>Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet</p>
    </div>

    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
  </div>
</div></footer>
```

### Update 1

```css
div.column { float: left; }

div#footer div.wrapper div.column { width:50%; }

div#footer div.wrapper div.column:nth-child(3) {
  clear:both;
}

/*For testing purposes... */

div.column {
  background: black;
  color:white;
  border: 1px solid red;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

```html
<footer><div id="footer">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="column">
      <h4>Important Links</h4>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="index.php">Homepage</a></li>
        <li><a href="./privacy.php">Privacy Policy</a></li>
        <li><a href="./terms.php">Terms of Use</a></li>
      </ul>

      <h4>Social</h4>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-fw"></i>Twitter</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-linkedin fa-fw"></i>LinkedIn</a></li>
      </ul>   
    </div>

    <div class="column">
      <p>Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet</p>    
    </div>

    <div class="column">
      <p>Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet</p>
    </div>

    <div class="column" style="text-align:right;">
      <p>Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet</p>
    </div>

    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
  </div>
</div></footer>
```

Comment: The current workaround is similar, but is there no way to just have an `:after` css pseudo-element acting as a clearfix, rather than adding new rules/elements?

Comment: Edited my answer. Now it will automatically clear the third element without you having to add a new class to the element. The trick is not to clear the :after of the second column, but to just clear the third column. And I'm not sure you can use with :nth-child and :after at the same time. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way:
Use a container for de line. The line container has two elements then you do not need to use `clear:both`.

HTML code:

```
<footer>
    <div id="line-1" class="line">
        <div id="column-1" class="column">1</div>
        <div id="column-2" class="column">2</div>
    </div>
    <div id="line-2" class="line">
        <div id="column-3" class="column">3</div>
        <div id="column-4" class="column">4</div>
    </div>

</footer>
```

CSS code:

```
footer{
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:400px;

}

.line{
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    height:200px;
}

.column{
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    width:50%;
    height:200px;
}

#column-1{
    background-color:red;
}

#column-2{
    background-color:blue;
}
#column-3{
    background-color:green;
}
#column-4{
    background-color:yellow;
}
```

See this example working at: https://jsfiddle.net/wtvmybck/

Answer (score -1):

Group the blocks per two in wrappers, set the wrapper to 50% by default and 100% on smaller screens.

```css
div.column { float: left; }

div#footer div.wrapper div.column { width:50%; }

div#footer div.wrapper div.column:nth-child(2):after {
  content:'';
  display:block;
  clear:both;
}

/*For testing purposes... */

div.column_wrapper {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div.column {
  background: black;
  color:white;
  border: 1px solid red;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

```html
<footer><div id="footer">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="column_wrapper">
    <div class="column">
      <h4>Important Links</h4>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="index.php">Homepage</a></li>
        <li><a href="./privacy.php">Privacy Policy</a></li>
        <li><a href="./terms.php">Terms of Use</a></li>
      </ul>

      <h4>Social</h4>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-fw"></i>Twitter</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-linkedin fa-fw"></i>LinkedIn</a></li>
      </ul>   
    </div>

    <div class="column">
      <p>Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet</p>    
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="column_wrapper">
    <div class="column">
      <p>Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet</p>
    </div>

    <div class="column" style="text-align:right;">
      <p>Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet</p>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
  </div>
</div></footer>
```

Comment: The current workaround is similar, but is there no way to just have an `:after` css pseudo-element acting as a clearfix, rather than adding new rules/elements?

Comment: Personally I would not use a clearfix at all. Just learn to how html/css properly ;)